# Print out a SQL single query (Yii 1.x)

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-components

I have a massive query that is generated using CDbCriteria as shown below:-

```
$schema = Yii::app()->db->schema;
$builder = $schema->commandBuilder;

// how to echo out this query?
$command = $builder->createFindCommand($schema->getTable('myuser'), $criteria);
$results = $command->queryAll();
```

I know I can use the 'logging' feature of Yii to view the query, is it possible to just echo out this single query (as opposed to having Yii show me tons of other queries that are being run on the page).

Comment: The easiest way I've found for this is to put a typo in the sql, it throws an error and all the sql is on the screen!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can print query built by query builder by using `$command->text`.
In your example code will be:

```
    $schema = Yii::app()->db->schema;
    $builder = $schema->commandBuilder;
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $command = $builder->createFindCommand($schema->getTable('name_of_table'), $criteria);
    $results = $command->text;
    echo $results;
```

`$command->text` will return your complete query text

Comment: @Zabs absolute pleasure :)

Comment: if I add `$criteria->with = ['relation'];` in `$command->text` I can't see JOIN. How can I use `with` here?

Answer (score 3):

> Add this in your config file. You can see the query and other details
>   at the bottom of the page.

```
'db'=>array(
        'enableProfiling'=>true,
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
),
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        …
        array(
            'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'profile',
            'enabled'=>true,
        ),
    ),
),
```